# PerformSegueWithIdentifier does not work

Tags: ios, swift, segue, agent

I am trying to use use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` to change the view on the Storyboard when a JSON file loaded remotely. For this I am using the Swift Class "Agent" to perform the HTTP request. Everything is working when I write the

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toView2", sender: self)
```

out of the "done" variable. Why is it not working? I guess it has something to do with the "sender: self". But I don't know how to solve this. I don't get any errors on Xcode. It just loads the data from my server and then nothing happens...

```
    @IBAction func goToView2(sender: AnyObject) {
    let done = { (response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, data: Agent.Data!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        self.namesJSON = JSONValue(data!)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toView2", sender: self)
    };
    Agent.post("http://api.example.com/test.php", headers: [ "Header": "Value" ],
        data: [ "test": "ok" ], done: done)
}
```

Comment: Does the closure get called at all?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Edited: (I've put a slightly different answer in the first place)

Basically, the problem is that you have entered a side queue

and by just getting the main queue and invoking the segue in it, it will work quite fine.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toView2", sender: self)
}
```

Hope it works

Comment: I'm getting `Receiver () has no segue with identifier`