# performSegue(withSender: sender:) does not work - no errors displayed

Tags: swift, segue, swift3, xcode8

```
func checkForRecipes(noRecords: Bool) {

    //segue to addNewRecipe page

    if noRecords == true{

        print("Can't Find any Recipes!")

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToAddNewRecipeVC", sender: self)

    }else{

        print("error, noRecords not equal to zero")
    }
```

I am able to segue successfully via the storyboard but want to do so programmatically based on information returned from a delegate.

Upon running the app, the information from the delegate is successfully sent to the function "checkForRecipes" -i.e "noRecords" returns TRUE, but for some reason, the below line of code within that function does not seem to execute (and no errors are thrown):

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToAddNewRecipeVC", sender: self)`

The app starts up but stops at the main screen, whereas it should segue to the "AddNewRecipe" view controller.

The segue itself definitely has a segue ID of "ToAddNewRecipeVC". I have also tried dispatching to the main queue (to no avail) based on the following [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982722/performseguewithidentifier-does-not-work)

I'm stumped - what's going wrong here?

Comment: Using screenshot's for code is frowned upon.  Place your code in the question.

Comment: @MwcsMac: I have replaced the screenshot with a clip of code.

Comment: where checkForRecipes() is called ?

Comment: check if everything is set up right. You can use my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39930180/5327882 to a quite similar issue. In the end it was just a wrong view controller which was set up in the code

Comment: @Azimov: "noRecords" is sent to checkForRecipes() from another class via the delegate pattern.

Comment: @ronatory: Thanks for the link - it looks as though I should be good - segue ID set, each of the two view controllers have their own custom class set and both view controllers are indeed of type UIViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it looks as though I have solved the problem. I embedded the main view controller into a navigation controller and now everything works as intended. I tried this same tactic earlier and it kept throwing up errors. grrr!

Anyway - thank you to all for the input!